# Trying to install Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm a beginner learning python. I'm trying to install Scrapy onto my Mac.

I have installed using the standard

```
pip install Scrapy
```

However, when I try to use Scrapy I get the following error message

```
 ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (init_openssl)
```

What has gone wrong with the installation? Or am I missing something else?

Comment: try to update your openssl? or pyopenssl

Comment: I did this with homebrew but I am still getting the same error message

Comment: Created virtualenv? For some reason working in a virtual env works flawlessly, whole normal install breaks sometime.